# How Select Table Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

How Select table row based on table header and First Column Values.
Can you please help me this Using JavaScript or jQuery .
Please find the attache image [image] for your reference.

Comment: What have you tried? Give it a shot and ask here if you run into something that can't be solved with a little googling and searching across SO.

Answer (score -1):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var json = {1: 'AOC', 2: 'BAs', 3: 'CTS:ELE', 4: 'COE:DEV'};
        $('table#xss tr').each(function () {
            var type = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            var res = type.split(";");
            var thisRow = $(this);
            $.each(json, function (key, val) {
                for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    if (val == res[i].trim()) {
                        var cc = parseInt(key) + 2;
                        thisRow.find('td:nth-child(' + cc + ')').html('****')
                    }
                }
//            
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Change the content in row 1, col 5:

```
$("#box tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(5)").html("hehe");
```